# Calculate premium for claim, the principle of zero utility

Tags: utility

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    X&0&200&400&800&1000&2000\\  \hline
\mathbb{P}&0.4&0.2&0.1&0.1&0.1&0.1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
The principle of zero utility formula:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}u(x+\pi(X)-X)=u(w).
\end{equation}

I am given $u(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $w=10000$. Now

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\sqrt{10000+\pi(X)-X}=\sqrt{10000}.
\end{equation}

I know I cannot just simply square everything and get my result. What is the way to get $\pi(X)$? I found similar question ([Quadratic Utility Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134571/quadratic-utility-function)) and understand the whole procedure with quadratic utility function.

Comment: As you mentioned, direct calculation is not the right way to approach this problem. I don't know the answer, but you could try finding an MGF for X. In addition, $\sqrt{1 + X}$ has a nice Taylor series. So you can use that Taylor series and the MGF to get a quick estimate.

Comment: @PavanC. You are right, I haven't thought of Taylor series. Thank you!